# Division with really big numbers

Tags: math, numbers, division

I was just wondering what different strategies there are for division when dealing with big numbers. By big numbers, I mean ~50 digit numbers .

e.g. 
9237639100273856744937827364095876289200667937278 / 8263744826271827396629934467882946252671

When both numbers are big, long division seems to lose its usefulness...

I thought one possibility is to count through multiplications of the divisor until you go over the dividend, but if it was the dividend in the example above divided by a small number, e.g. 4, then that's a huge amount of calculations to do.

So, is there  simple, clean way to do this?

Comment: You could just use Python (1117851445), or you could be more specific about the context in which you want to solve this.

Comment: If you're interested in division algorithms, several approaches are covered in [Modern Computer Arithmetic](http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/mca/pub226.html), which is free to download.  I'll admit it can be a little slow going, but there's lots of good information there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What language / platform do you use? This is most likely already solved, so you don't need to implement it from scratch. E.g. Haskell has the `Integer` type, Java the `java.math.BigInteger` class, .NET the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` structure, etc.

If your question is really a theoretical one, I suggest you read Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 4.3.1. What you are looking for is called "Algorithm D" there. Here is a C implementation of that algorithm along with a short explanation: 
http://hackers-delight.org.ua/059.htm

Comment: I'm using Obj-c but I'm trying to create my own implementation, instead of using pre-existing ones

Thanks for the reference to Knuth, do you know if there is a way to read that section online, or do I need to go to a library?

Comment: You might get lucky on Google books (in my edition of the book the algorithm starts on page 273). But if you just search for: -- kunth division "algorithm d" -- you will find some examples and explanations like the one in my link above.

Comment: On a second thought: If you have never read Knuth, look on the web first. For example Kunth uses Pseudo Assembly instead of the Pseudocode you are used to from other algorithm books.

Answer (score 1):

[Long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) is not very complicated if you are working with binary representations of your numbers and probably the most efficient algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't need very exact result, you can use logarithms and exponents.
Exponent is the function f(x)=e^x, where e is a mathmaticall constant equal to 2.71828182845...
Logarithm (marked by ln) is the inverse of the exponent.

Since ln(a/b)=ln(a)-ln(b), to calculate a/b you need to:
Calculate ln(a) and ln(b) [By library function, logarithm table or other methods]
substruct them: temp=ln(a)-lb(b)
calculate the exponent e^temp

Comment: I need an exact result :\

Although I can chop off decimals/remainders, but I need the exact number rounded down to the nearest integer

Comment: Whell, mathmatically it is exact, buy the problem is that ln(a) abd ln(b) have to be rounded.

Comment: In your example, the real result is 1117851445. ln(a) is near 112.747, and ln(b) is near 91.912. e^the difference gives 1118215558. The same process with 5 digits after point gives 1117857786, and with 9 digits after point gives the real result.